# Store activity with dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a structural MySQL question about storing events in a database with dates.

Say that an organiser would select a range of dates, eg:

> ["19/12/2014","20/12/2014","26/12/2014","27/12/2014","02/01/2015","03/01/2015","09/01/2015","10/01/2015"]

The event needs to be saved into a table, I'm thinking about creating a many-to-many table with the structure:

```
event_id  |  start_date  |  end_date
```

Now when thinking about it, this would mean that I'd need to convert the date array into an array of object with beginning - end date.
Now the alternative would be to just create a table that looks like this:

```
event_id  |  event_date
```

And create a separate record for every date.
The purpose is obviously to check which events should be sent back to the client within a given date range.

Which of the two options seems to common / viable?
It is pretty crucial for the setup.

Comment: Is it usual to create the date ranges in the client based on the array in the example? I can't immediately find a library to do this, so I wondered if this is a common strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.  If the first event ends on the date of the second event, you can go with event_id | event_date, but otherwise I'd go with the first option.

If you don't have the end date somehow, then how will you be able to tell the client the range of dates for the event?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with setup that contains event duration (in seconds) - it's flexible.

```
event_id (int) | start_date (datetime) | duration (int)
```

In this case when event duration does not matter - put 0 there in other case just put the number o seconds so you will be able to store event which lasts days or just a few hours or minutes.

Comment: Thanks, but for our application, I won't go into time granularity. Duration in terms of number of days is interesting though, but it means that I have to calculate adjacent dates in the client. Since I didn't find js libraries to do this, I wondered if it is common practice.

Comment: Also, it seems hard to query for a given date.

Comment: You can always query for given date using `start_date` and you can always calculate end_date with simple `DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL duration SECOND)` - hope that helps.

Comment: Converting the dates into multiple date ranges doesn't seem to be a problem necessarily. But it cannot be the purpose to calculate the intersection for every record in the table because I believe that it will be terribly slow.

Comment: It is slow for sure - to calculate it for whole dataset. That's why it depends what operations you will need to perform using this data structure. I'm using this structure to store bookings and it does the job, because I never have to query by the end_date.

Comment: It just needs to retrieve events based on a given date range. That's why I thought about the single dates column that I could index which could make retrievals fast (distinct select on event id).

Comment: so skip the end date - option 1